# how to fix the problem of not entering to Try block in android studio?

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I am developing an android application. actually, my database is on localhost. I've developed my API using PHP. for the login page in android studio, I need to check if the user login credential is correct or not. I'm facing a problem when I want to deserialize the json that I've gotten from the API; the problem of not entering to the Try block!would you please check it and write for me what is the solution?

I checked if my API is working and I'm getting right json; this is a json from one of my login attempt:

```
{"status":"success","user_count":1,"user":{"id":"2","username":"yasi","password":"yasi"}}
```

I put a "Log" command at first of my class to check if the class is called and starts; it starts but is ignoring Try block and goes to the Catch block.

```
public void jsonToUser (String jsonUser){
    String username,password,user_count;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonUser);

        username = jsonObject.getString("username");
        password = jsonObject.getString("password");
        user_count=jsonObject.getString("user_count");
        if(user_count.equals("1"))
        {
            if (!username.equals("admin"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomePageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AdminHomePageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I expect the next activity to be shown if I enter correct user login credential.

First of all, I am working on a Fragment and not an Activity.

secondly, this is the code to call my API in OnCreateView():

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new CheckUserLoginAsync().execute("http://10.0.2.2:80/whereToEatAPI/api/check_user_login_api.php"
                        ,txtUsername.getText().toString()
                        ,txtPassword.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Did you try to step through with a debugger? What is the last executed line?

Comment: Please paste you API Call code and from where you are calling this jsonToUser()

Comment: What you describe is impossible. If it goes to the catch block, then it means that it went to the try block and a JSONException was thrown in that block. The error and stack trace of the exception will tell you (and us) what the problem is **if you read it (post it)**.

Comment: For getting more details on this a good thing can be to do `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON has this structure:

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "user_count":1,
  "user": {
    "id":"2",
    "username":"yasi",
    "password":"yasi"
  }
}
```

So this line

```
username = jsonObject.getString("username");
```

is not going to return "yasi" as you probably expect, because "username" is a field of "user," not of the top level object. It is either going to throw an exception, or return null, in which case the code that checks if `username` is "admin" will throw an exception. Either way, you wind up in the catch.

Simply printing the result of `getMessage()` when you catch an exception is usually not a good idea because the "message" for `NullPointerException` is simply "null." (Not sure if this is because there is no message, or because the message actually says "null," but the effect is the same.) NPEs are very common, and "null" is rarely a useful error message, so you should always print at least the type of exception, or call `printStackTrace`, or just pass the entire exception to the logger, which will usually do the right thing with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Gson for best and optimized code
>
> Add Gson dependency in gradle :
>
> ```
> implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
> ```

Now add two model classes in project

**Login.class**

```
public class Login {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("user_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer userCount;
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private User user;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getUserCount() {
        return userCount;
    }

    public void setUserCount(Integer userCount) {
        this.userCount = userCount;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

and **User.class**

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

now replace json deserialization with this

```
public void jsonToUser (String jsonUser){
        String username,password,user_count;
        try {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Login login =gson.fromJson(jsonUser, Login.class);

            username = login.getUser().getUsername();
            user_count = String.valueOf(login.getUserCount());
            password = login.getUser().getPassword();

            if(user_count.equals("1"))
            {
                if (!username.equals("admin"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AdminHomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is an optimized and better way to do json parsing rather than manual parsing.

Comment: Optimized for what?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn optimized for parsing of response from API.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing username direct but it is in user object. So first get user object then try to get username and other fieilds.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonUser);
JSONObject jsonObjectUser=jsonObject.getJSONObject("user");

username = jsonObjectUser.getString("username");
password = jsonObjectUser.getString("password");
user_count=jsonObjectUser.getString("user_count");
```